# I am stuck with some prime number problems. Are there any hints you could give me?

Tags: prime-numbers

1. Find all natural values of n which make the value of (n^3 - 1)/5 a prime number.
2. Find all values of p which make p, p + 2 and p + 4 prime numbers.
3. Find all prime numbers p which also make p + 10 and p + 20 prime too.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Problem two HINT: Consider modulo 3.

Comment: ditto problem three

Comment: Hint on (1): $x=\frac{n^3-1}{5}=\frac{(n-1)(n^2+n+1)}{5}$. $x$ (if it is an integer) has  integer factors $>1$ and is not prime unless either $n-1=1$ or $\frac{n-1}{5}=1$

Answer (score 0):

$\hspace0.5cm$   (1) It is rather easy to show that the only $n$ is $6$.

$\hspace0.5cm$ (2) A prime $p\gt3$ is of the form $3n+1$ or $3n+2$ so we have
$$3n+1,3n+3,3n+5 \text { or }3n+2,3n+5,3n+6$$ In both cases one of the three numbers is divisible by $3$. Thus the only example is $(p,p+2,p+4)=(3,5,7)$.

$\hspace0.5cm$ (3) Proceding as in (2) we have $$3n+11,3n+21\text { or }3n+12,3n+22$$ and again one of the numbers will be multiple of $3$.